# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am new at machine learning, I am using Jupyter notebook. I am trying to install TensorFlow 1.14.0 by using the following code:

```
!pip install imageai
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)`
```

and I am getting this error: 
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '**version**' 
any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem, and installing `tensorflow==1.14.0` alongside `tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0` fixed it:

```
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```