# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'version' despite being installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-lab, attributeerror

I have installed TF 2.12.0 in a conda environment 'tf' and am getting this error in JupyterLab IPYNB Notebook, running in 'tf' kernel. (Following this tutorial) `[link](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/)`

Running this code gives me attribute error

```
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.version)
```

Error Log:

```
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==2.12.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-intel==2.12.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras<2.13,>=2.12.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=1.0.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.24,>=1.22 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.13,>=2.12.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast<=0.4.0,>=0.2.1 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.6 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.9.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.53.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse>=1.6.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: libclang>=13.0.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (16.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=2.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (23.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.1 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt<1.15,>=1.11.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jax>=0.3.15 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (58.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.37.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.7 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jax>=0.3.15->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ml-dtypes>=0.0.3 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jax>=0.3.15->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.4 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (6.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\esc\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow-intel==2.12.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.2.2)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 3
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install tensorflow==2.12.0')
      2 import tensorflow as tf
----> 3 print(tf.__version__)
      4 print(tf.version)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Using version gives same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 2
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 print(tf.version)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'version'
```

The rest of code also gives same error:

```
import keras_cv
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


# Instantiate the Stable Diffusion model
model = keras_cv.models.StableDiffusion(img_height=512, img_width=512, jit_compile=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 import keras_cv
      2 from tensorflow import keras
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras_cv\__init__.py:18
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     14 
     15 # isort:off
     16 from keras_cv import version_check
---> 18 version_check.check_tf_version()
     19 # isort:on
     21 from keras_cv import callbacks

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras_cv\version_check.py:25, in check_tf_version()
     24 def check_tf_version():
---> 25     if parse(tf.__version__) < parse(MIN_VERSION):
     26         raise RuntimeError(
     27             f"The Tensorflow package version needs to be at least {MIN_VERSION} "
     28             "for KerasCV to run. Currently, your TensorFlow version is "
     29             f"{tf.__version__}. Please upgrade with `$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow`. "
     30             "You can use `pip freeze` to check afterwards that everything is ok."
     31         )

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

`! conda list` gives these results for tensorflow packages:

```
tensorboard-data-server   0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-intel          2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

[Complete CONDA PACKAGES:](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1viNEtith96ORPuBua3s8l0x2KKsGku-wPjTZUNKhZlk/edit?usp=sharing)

I cannot figure out why is this error happening? I Already read other solutions but they didn't work, like [this ]([AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554548/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-)
version)one

[THIS](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/795#issuecomment-449714942) suggested that there are 2 different kinds of TF: so i have already uninstalled this one : tensorflow-base 2.10.0 and restarted everything, now there is only 1 TF version but same error persists

Comment: What output do you get when you run this code?

```import os, pathlib, itertools; next(p for p in itertools.accumulate(pathlib.Path('c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\versions.py').parts, os.path.join) if not os.path.exists(p))```

Comment: @fakedad I get this  :
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 next(p for p in itertools.accumulate(pathlib.Path('c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\versions.py').parts, os.path.join) if not os.path.exists(p))

StopIteration: "

Comment: If you have a script `tensorflow.py`, rename it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні i just have an IPYNB file 'SD.ipynb', no script named tensorflow.py

Comment: I am able to replicate the code successfully without any error on the given configuration (python 3.9 and TensorFlow 2.12) using jupyter notebook. There could be an issue with how you install TensorFlow in your system. Please follow the [step by step instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install TensorFlow by creating a new VirEnv and try again running your code. The right code to check the TensorFlow version is : `import tensorflow as tf` `tf.__version__` or `tf.version.VERSION`. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні do you know [what 'Слава Україні' means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slava_Ukraini)?